# How to take aggregate of a data Grouped by Financial Year in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by

My Financial Year is between  1st July to 30th June e.g 2018-07-01 and 2019-06-30

I have following data.

[image: Data]

i want to aggregate of **Rate** column by financial year in sql
please help.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Provide sample data as text, not as an image. Also provide desired results.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Are you aware that financial year can change? A calendar table is the best way to implement this.

Comment: Do you want the first date or the last date of fiscal year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood what you're looking for, this should work for you.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Rate) as Rate,
    CASE WHEN MONTH(FromDate) < 7 THEN YEAR(FromDate) - 1 ELSE YEAR(FromDate) END AS Fiscal_Year
FROM #t
GROUP BY CASE WHEN MONTH(FromDate) < 7 THEN YEAR(FromDate) - 1 ELSE YEAR(FromDate) END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the financial year by either subtracting or adding six months.

In ANSI/ISO standard SQL, this looks like:

```
select extract(year from fromDate + interval '6 month') as fiscal_year
       sum(rate)
from t
group by extract(year from fromDate + interval '6 month');
```

This uses standard SQL -- which ironically does not work in most databases.  Date functions are notoriously database-specific, so the exact code might differ in your database (which is unspecified as I write this).